# AppCompatActivity OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, android

I wanna add toolbar to my android app, however I got "FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         java.lang.OutOfMemoryError" when I changed Activity to AppCompatActivity. Here is my code, I don't know why changing a line makes an out of memory error.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

public class Notifications extends AppCompatActivity {
//public class Notifications extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_notifications);
        //Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        //setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);

        //String[] notificationsDates = {"12Jan 2016", "14Feb 2016", "22Feb 2016", "18Dec 2015", "2Nov 2015", "20Oct 2015", "15Oct 2015"};
        //String[] estimationTimes = {"9:00 am", "10:00 am", "11:00 am", "9:00 am", "10:00 am", "10:00 am", "11:00 am"};
        final SingleNotification[] notifications = {
            new SingleNotification("12Jan2016","9:00 am",R.drawable.fedex,false),
            new SingleNotification("14Feb2016","10:00 am",R.drawable.ups,false),
            new SingleNotification("22Feb2016","11:00 am",R.drawable.purolator,true),
            new SingleNotification("18Dec2015","9:00 am",R.drawable.dhl,true),
            new SingleNotification("2Nov2015","10:00 am",R.drawable.fedex,true),
            new SingleNotification("20Oct2015","10:00 am",R.drawable.ups,true),
            new SingleNotification("15Oct2015","11:00 am",R.drawable.ups,true)
    };
            ListAdapter listAdapter = new CustomeAdapter(this, notifications);
            ListView notificationListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.notificationsList);
        notificationListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        notificationListView.setOnItemClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        String date = String.valueOf(notifications[position].getDeliveryDate());
                        Toast.makeText(Notifications.this, date, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
        );

    }

    //String[] notificationsDate = {"Delivery Data: 17Feb2015"};
    //String[] notificationsTime = {" Estimated Time: "};
}
```

here is CustomAdapter:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.app.Activity;

public class CustomeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SingleNotification> {

CustomeAdapter(Context context, SingleNotification[] notifications) {
    super(context, R.layout.custome_row, notifications);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View customView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custome_row, parent, false);

        SingleNotification notification = getItem(position);
        LinearLayout singleNotificationLayout = (LinearLayout)     customView.findViewById(R.id.singleNotificationLayout);
    TextView deliveryDateText = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.delivaryDataText);
    TextView notificationNumberText = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.notificationNumberText);
    TextView estimationTimeText = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.estimationTimeText);
    ImageView logoImage = (ImageView)     customView.findViewById(R.id.logoImage);

        deliveryDateText.setText(notification.getDeliveryDate());
        notificationNumberText.setText(String.valueOf(position + 1));
        estimationTimeText.setText(notification.getEstimationTime());
        logoImage.setImageResource(notification.getImageID());
        if (notification.getIsDelivered())
        singleNotificationLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#6d6d6d"));
        else
        singleNotificationLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF40459A"));
        return customView;
    }
}
```

here is the log:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
                                                                         at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                                                                         at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:501)
                                                                         at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:354)
                                                                         at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:785)
                                                                         at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1970)
                                                                         at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:660)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:323)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.TintManager.getDrawable(TintManager.java:175)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.TintManager.getDrawable(TintManager.java:168)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource(AppCompatImageHelper.java:51)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageResource(AppCompatImageView.java:72)
                                                                               at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2143)
                                                                         at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1831)
                                                                         at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:674)
                                                                         at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1332)
                                                                         at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1630)
                                                                         at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1994)
                                                                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
                                                                         at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1021)
                                                                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
                                                                         at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1037)
                                                                         at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:747)
                                                                         at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
                                                                         at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1156)
                                                                         at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:760)
                                                                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
                                                                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
                                                                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
                                                                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
                                                                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
                                                                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
                                                                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
                                                                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
                                                                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1892)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1711)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
                                                                         at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
                                                                         at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
                                                                         at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
                                                                         at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
```

Comment: always add full logcat

Comment: Please add the logcat details.

Comment: I think it's likely youll need to show us what CustomeAdapter is doing too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem as you can see is in your adapter (`at com...timesavvi.CustomeAdapter.getView(CustomeAdapter.java:36)`).

The culprit would seem to be `logoImage.setImageResource(notification.getImageID());` (which I assume is ln 36)

What this will mean is the image to which getImageID points is a very large file which is not suitable for the device. You should use scaled images for the various densities and not use particularly large dimensions in order to avoid this issue.

Bear in mind as well that in an adpater any code you write can be called dozens of times, depending on how many rows you have in your recycler/list view and that if you are decoding from a network resource, it may continue to do that in the background for rows which arent even on the screen any more, so you need to manage such calls if you use them

Comment: Thank you very much Nick, I am wondering why this didn't happen when I use Activity?

Comment: I can't tell you for sure without looking into the AOSP Activity class and seeing what it is doing to manage this problem. But it's an easy issue to avoid/manage now you know what to look for!